# The data couldn’t be read because it is missing. GET Request

Tags: ios, swift

```
struct DriverProfileStruct: Codable {
    let first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, phone: String
    let address: String
    let autoType: Int
    let autoTechPassPhoto, trailerTechPassPhoto, autoOwnerPass, driverPass: String
    let driverLicense, internationalTransportationLicense, insurancePolicy: String
}
```

it is my struct and when I am requesting it I have problem:
The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

```
        ServerManager.shared.getDriverProfileInfo(token: UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "token") as! String, { (data) in
            self.data = [data]
            self.lnameLabelT = data.last_name
            self.phoneLabelT = data.phone
        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }
```

JSON data

```
{
    "first_name": "Адахан",
    "last_name": "Адаханов",
    "date_of_birth": "2020-05-13",
    "phone": "+996709075623",
    "address": "мкр 7",
    "auto_type": 2,
    "autoTechPassPhoto": "http://crmlogistics.herokuapp.com/media/static/blank-profile-picture-973460_6404.png",
    "trailerTechPassPhoto": "http://crmlogistics.herokuapp.com/media/static/blank-profile-picture-973460_6404.png",
    "autoOwnerPass": "http://crmlogistics.herokuapp.com/media/static/blank-profile-picture-973460_6404.png",
    "driverPass": "http://crmlogistics.herokuapp.com/media/static/blank-profile-picture-973460_6404.png",
    "driverLicense": "http://crmlogistics.herokuapp.com/media/static/blank-profile-picture-973460_6404.png",
    "internationalTransportationLicense": "http://crmlogistics.herokuapp.com/media/static/blank-profile-picture-973460_6404.png",
    "insurancePolicy": "http://crmlogistics.herokuapp.com/media/static/blank-profile-picture-973460_6404.png"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this in your `DriverProfileStruct` struct. Because in codable you have to decode key using CodingKey if is different from your variable name

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case autoType = "auto_type"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have now: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: try changing data type of autoType Int to Double.